# Probability of rank between normal distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

Consider the three normal distributions

$$ X \sim  \mathcal{N}(\mu_x,\sigma_x) $$
$$ Y \sim  \mathcal{N}(\mu_y,\sigma_y) $$
$$ Z \sim  \mathcal{N}(\mu_z,\sigma_z) $$

$x_i$, $y_i$ and $z_i$ denotes independent random draws from each distribution.

First I wish to compute the probability that
$$ \mathbb{P}_{x1} = \mathbb{P}(x_i > y_i  \land x_i > z_i)  $$
then
$$ \mathbb{P}_{x3} = \mathbb{P}(x_i < y_i  \land x_i < z_i)  $$
which gives me
$$ \mathbb{P}_{x2} = 1-\mathbb{P}_{x1}-\mathbb{P}_{x3} $$

and ultimately I can construct the matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{P}_{x1} & \mathbb{P}_{x2} & \mathbb{P}_{x3}\\
\mathbb{P}_{y1} & \mathbb{P}_{y2} & \mathbb{P}_{y3}\\
\mathbb{P}_{z2} & \mathbb{P}_{z2} & \mathbb{P}_{z3}
\end{bmatrix} $$

but first things first.
How do I establish

$$ \mathbb{P}_{x1} = \mathbb{P}(x_i > y_i  \land x_i > z_i)  $$
The probability that a random draw from X is larger than both a random draw from Y and a random draw from Z?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution

Comment: $$\mathbb P(X_i > Y_i  \land X_i > Z_i)=\mathbb P(X_i > \max\{Y_i, Z_i\})$$

Comment: You need to evaluate these quantities numerically.

Comment: Yes, so i am looking for $$ P(X_i > max(Y_i,Z_i))$$ but im not sure how to attack the problem.